# Symfony2 Translatable choose language / skip translation

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

Is it possible to get a specific translation in twig or to skip the translation?
I want to get an english translation for a specific field undependant from the current locale

Comment: You can set a fallback locale and in the other locales just not translate it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can force a locale like this:

```
{% trans with {'%name%': 'Fabien'} from "app" into "fr" %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}
```

Found in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates).